# How to carry out MVC in developing html/js/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, model-view-controller

Is it possible?

The ultimate goal I want to achieve is that:

When I want to add a new feature to a page,just do something like:

```
importhtml(html.file);
importcss(css.file);
importjs(js.file);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an MVC framework which is all javascript driven, take a look at http://www.sproutcore.com/.